# parallel indexing in pandas dataframe using a pandas series?

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, pandas

If i have a data frame that looks like this:

a      b      c      d
0    10 15     23    56
1    11    64    66    34
2    46    98    56    87
3    3     49     89    100
4    57    32    48    27
5    99    68    35    19
6    65    79    95    91
8    79    44    66    92

The indicies that I am interested in for each column is as follows (the indicdes are in the form of a series):
      a    b    c    d
0    3    5    8    1

So the result I would want is
      a    b      c      d
0    3    68    66    34

I want to be able to pull out result

I can convert the indicies into a array if need be but the goal is to index these different columns in parallel.

Comment: This does what you want but not sure how useful it is: `pd.DataFrame({'a':[df.a[3]], 'b':[df.b[5]], 'c':[df.c[8]], 'd':[df.d[1]]})`

Comment: I can't use this when I have hundreds of columns.  It's doable when I have only an handful of columns

Comment: you can use the lookup method: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/indexing.html#the-lookup-method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`DataFrame.lookup`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.lookup.html), and then build a new frame.  Not the prettiest, but:

```
>>> s
a    3
b    5
c    8
d    1
Name: 0, dtype: int64
>>> df.lookup(s.values, s.keys())
array([ 3, 68, 66, 34])
>>> pd.DataFrame(dict(zip(s.keys(), df.lookup(s.values, s.keys()))), index=[0])
   a   b   c   d
0  3  68  66  34
```

where I'm assuming that we're using `s`, which is a `Series`, to hold the indices.

Comment: Perfect! Just what I wanted!